# How to call a registered SPIN function in Allegrograph with AGWebView?

Tags: sparql, allegrograph, spin-rdf

I'm using Allegrograph as my triplestore and I try to use SPIN functions. I managed to register a simple SPIN function via the HTTP API of the AGWebView tool. Now, I'm trying to call the SPIN function in a SPARQL query, but AGWebView tells me it cannot find the registered SPIN function. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: If possible, give us a short code excerpt of what you tried, it will be hard to tell without that.

Comment: Is this related to 'Spin' - the formal verification technology?

Comment: Hi, SPIN stands for SPARQL Inferencing Notation. It can be used to define SPARQL queries, add them to your triple-store and reuse them in other SPARQL queries.

Comment: I used the AdvancedRest client for Chrome to do a PUT action to put a SPIN function into the triple-store. The triple-store is called "anyname" and located at localhost:10035. This leads to

{http://localhost:10035/repositories/anyname/spin/function}

and the result is

{uri: <ex:test>
query: select ?s where {?s ?p ?o}
arguments: ?bla}

When calling the ex:test function with the following query

select ?o
where
{
?s ex:test (?o)
}

it gives the result that the query has constants that are not in the store (namely ex:test). Then, where is it?